# I did the same "printf", but different results came out

Tags: c

it's simple code.

it shouldn't print a:(null).

it should be a:Mon Jul 31 14:33:39 2017

why print a:(null) ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    time_t currentTime;
    char c_time_string[26];


        currentTime = time(NULL);
        if (currentTime == (time_t)-1 )
        {
            (void)fprintf(stderr, "Failure to obtain the current time. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ctime_s(c_time_string, 26, &currentTime);
        if ( c_time_string == NULL)
        {
            (void)fprintf(stderr, "Failure to obtain the current time. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        (void)printf("a: %d \n a:%s \n", currentTime, c_time_string);
        (void)printf("b: %s", c_time_string);
        getchar();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: I suspect a `time_t` type is too large to fit the `%d` format. So you get null (`printf` tries to interpret the upper part of `time_t` as a string pointer). Try using `%ld`.

Comment: You have `a:` twice in the format string. Which one is printing `(null)`?

Comment: Note that `c_time_string` can never be NULL; it is a local array.  You should be checking the return value from [`ctime_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ey61ayt.aspx), not looking at the data.  It returns 0 on success, and other values on failure.

Comment: i added my code as plain text

Comment: it appeared null when i used ("a: %s", c_time_string) next to (a: %d, currentTime)....   but last line at "(void)printf("b: %s", c_time_string);" print right value

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? The `%d` is expecting a value of type `int` on the stack when it prints, not a type the size of a `time_t`. And rather than `%ld` as I mentioned before, try `%lu` or possibly `%llu` to accommodate the size of a `time_t`.

Comment: yes, i read. but problem is %s....

Comment: No the problem isn't the `%s`. The problem is the prior `%d` because the `%s` is picking up what's left on the `printf` all stack when the `%d` leaves some of the `time_t` value there. You should try what I suggested and see what happens.

Comment: ok, makes sense. i will try

Comment: wow, it's work! thanks. Now I understand it exceed allocated space. how can i chose your answer? im newbie

Comment: Well, I just answered as a comment, so you can't really "accept" it in that mode, that's OK. Which format did you use, `%lu` or `%llu`?

Comment: %lu doesn't work, only %llu works. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem. see comments. there is answer